# How to configure and use Tuleap webdav plugin

Tags: plugins, webdav, tuleap

I have tried to configure and to use the webdav plugin in Tuleap but I am a bit lost.

I have exactly followed the help page of the webdav plugin (first option) and I do not know how to know if it works. Moreover I have the following message when I restart httpd service:

> Starting httpd: [Tue Apr 28 00:27:10 2015] [error] (EAI 2)Name or
>   service not known: Could not resolve host name
>   webdav.tuleaptest.maglo.fr -- ignoring!

Here you can find the configuration that I have used:

- **Tuleap server:**

  - OS: CentOS 6.7
  - Tuleap version: 8.6
  - Tuleap server name = tuleaptest.maglo.fr
  - Project name created in Tuleap = test
- **webdav plugin:**

  - sabredav_path = /usr/share/sabredav
  - webdav_base_uri = /
  - webdav_host = webdav.tuleaptest.maglo.fr
- **httpd configuration:**

> ...
>
> # Subversion virtual hosts alias
>
> #
>
> < VirtualHost *:80>
>
> ```
>      ServerName tuleaptest.maglo.fr
>      ServerAlias svn.*. tuleaptest.maglo.fr
>      Include conf.d/codendi_svnroot.conf
> ```
>
> < /VirtualHost>
>
> < VirtualHost webdav.tuleaptest.maglo.fr:80>
>
> ```
>      Include conf.d/php.conf
>      DocumentRoot /usr/share/codendi/plugins/webdav/www
>      AliasMatch ^/(.*) /usr/share/codendi/plugins/webdav/www/index.php
>      <Directory /usr/share/codendi/plugins/webdav/www>
>           Options Indexes MultiViews
>           AllowOverride None
>           Order allow,deny
>           Allow from all
>      </Directory>
> ```
>
> < /VirtualHost>
>
> #
>
> # Project web site virtual hosts alias
>
> #
>
> ...

Is there a mistake in my configuration ?

If there is no mistake, how can I use the webdav plugin in order to access from Nautilus for instance to the "documents" of the "test" project in Tuleap ?

Answer (score 0):

I answer to my question because after several attempts I have finally achieved to install and configure the plugin webdav for Tuleap. I have used the second option in the installation readme :

```
Under "/etc/httpd/conf.d/codendi_aliases.conf" add (in alias matches definition, add it to the beginning):

# 0- WebDAV plugin web/php pages 
AliasMatch ^/plugins/webdav/(.*) /usr/share/codendi/plugins/webdav/www/index.php
<DirectoryMatch "/usr/share/codendi/plugins/webdav/www/">
    Options Indexes MultiViews
    AllowOverride None
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</DirectoryMatch>

Then plugin configuration:
webdav_base_uri = "/plugins/webdav";
webdav_host     = "domain.tld":
```

Now in a web browser (chrome or firefox) I can access to the docman and files area by using in the address bar: https://domain.tld/plugins/webdav/

After indicating my login and my password, I can browse through the projects.